# compare two lists with siding window

Tags: python, sliding-window

Let's say I have a list of lists like

```
[[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]
```

and I have to compare this with my given list, let's say: `[0,0,1]` in order to get how many different items I have in a rolling window of dimension `3`, so in this case I should simply get the result `[2,2,2,2,3]` starting from the first element.

I am trying to find the most effective way to calculate this, thanks  to everybody for helping.

Comment: I find your example unclear. `[0,0,1]` and `[0,1,1]` have only one item different then why is corresponding item in result array set to `2`. Please rephrase your question by editing. also it'll be nice if you show what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how you got the result?

If you are trying to calculate the unique elements in each list, you can use set and find out the length of the set:

```
l = [[0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]

result = []

for items in l:
    unique_count = len(set(items))
    result.append(unique_count)
    
print(result)
```